# External hard drive issues and can I fix it myself?

Tags: hard-drive

I am having some issues with my external Hard drive. It seems to be the hard drive that is ‘broken’ as its not showing up on my current Mac or my old Mac either. I have tried to do a few things and follow some steps from online but nothing seems to be working for me. I have lots of important photos on the hard drive so really don’t want to loose the data. Thats the most important thing to me- retrieving the data from it.
I am not too bad with technology and with following instructions, I just don’t know what else to try. I can see the disk in disk utility but not in my finder window. The first listed disk seems to be ‘fine’ but the volume under it is the one that is having issues. When I run first aid the second one comes up with some errors but don’t know how to go about fixing them.
Even if someone could help me to get all the data off it and then erase it or something that would be fine too- just really want the data and don’t want to loose it! So frustrating that this has happened as Iv’e just transferred a large stack of my photos to it to clear up my computer space.
I have attached some photos for reference. I also did try mounting the disk and thats not working either.

Thanks heaps in advance!
Rachael[image]